# Migrating to LeaqueFlysystem SFTP from v1 to v3, how I can configure the V3 permissions to match the V1 directoryPerm?

Tags: php, configuration, sftp

In my composer I have the following dependency:

```
"league/flysystem-sftp": "^1.0",
```

And I upgraded into:

```
"league/flysystem-sftp-v3": "^3.0",
```

The existing code is:

```
        $adapter = new SftpAdapter([
            'host'          => $host,
            'port'          => $port,
            'username'      => $username,
            'privateKey'    => 'id-rsa',
            'root'          => '/',
            'timeout'       => 20,
            'directoryPerm' => 0755,
        ]);

        $sftp = new Filesystem($adapter);
```

According to the documetation I need to change the code ingo this:

```
$connectionProvider = new SftpConnectionProvider(
    $host,
    $username,
    null,
    'id-rsa.ppk',
    null,
    (int)$port,
    false,
    20
);

$visibility = PortableVisibilityConverter::fromArray([
   // IDK what to place here
]);

$adapter = new SftpAdapter($connectionProvider,"/",$visibility);

$sftp = new Filesystem($adapter);
```

But I have trouble to understand the following piece of documentation:
https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/adapter/sftp-v3/

I mean in my case I only have the setting:

```
            'directoryPerm' => 0755,
```

Whereas at documentation have:

```
 PortableVisibilityConverter::fromArray([
        'file' => [
            'public' => 0640,
            'private' => 0604,
        ],
        'dir' => [
            'public' => 0740,
            'private' => 7604,
        ],
    ])
```

And I have trouble to understand what I am supposed to place in here. The previous version of `flysystem-sftp` has a simpler approach whilst new one has to configure both `private` and `public` configuration of files.

Thereafter should I just configure it as?

```
$visibility = PortableVisibilityConverter::fromArray([
            'dir'=>[
                'private'=>0755,
                'public' => 0755
            ],
        ]);
```